# Plot multiple 2D graphs stored as a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, plot, matrix-indexing

I need to combine a fair amount (~15000) of plots on a single figure.
Doing it iteratively would take forever, so I stored all my data in a 3D matrix hoping I could plot all my data at once.

My matrix structure is as following :
[image: Matrix structure]

So, if I want to display the first plot of my matrix `M`, I type :

```
plot(M(:,1,1),M(:,2,1))
```

Naturally, to plot all my data at once, I tried :

```
plot(M(:,1,:),M(:,2,:))
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Error using plot
Data cannot have more than 2 dimensions.
```

Any ideas on how I could find a fast way to plot this kind of data?

Here is a code sample:

```
M = rand(5,2,3);

for i = 1:1:size(M,3)
    M(:,1,i) = linspace(1,size(M,1),size(M,1));
%     plot(M(:,1,i),M(:,2,i))  % Plot iteratively --> Works but slow
%     hold on 
end

plot(M(:,1,:),M(:,2,:)) % --> Gives the error 'Data cannot have more than 2 dimensions.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) your data, as it *is* inherently 2D, but merely permuted:

```
plot( squeeze(M(:,1,:)), squeeze(M(:,2,:)) )
```

A matrix like `M(:,1,:)` is of size 5x1x3, and what `squeeze` does is remove the intermediate dimension of size 1, yielding a 5x3 matrix. This can also be acheived using [`permute(M(:,1,:), [1,3,2])`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).